# Can't copy file from my ftp (linux server) in windows machine

Tags: linux, ftp, rhel5

- I getting this message whenever i try to download software from in ftp (linux,RHEL5) server
- I am using this ftp for LAN only

The error message as follows
[image]

Here i attached image as i get from cmd prompt , [image]

Comment: Please open cmd.exe, and type ftp 10.1.1.1  Then: ls -l pub/SOFTWARES then cd pub/SOFWARES/ and then ls -l . Please edit your question and append the output of these commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might trying setting explorer to use active mode ftp instead.  I found these instructions to do that on the net:

```
# Start Internet Explorer.
# Click Internet Options on the Tools menu.
# Click the Advanced tab.
# Uncheck the box "Enable Folder View for FTP sites"
# Uncheck the box "Use Passive FTP"
```

[Here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html) is a description of the difference between the two modes for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

use winscp software for the upload and download from you linux to win!!

http://winscp.net/eng/index.php